# MySQL fulltext against()

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, against

I am trying to create a search page with MySQL fulltext.

I have a search page with a textbox:

```
< FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="catalog.php?action=<?php echo $title; ?>">
```

I pass the user's input to another webpage (catalog.php) which runs the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (???)"
```

What do I place in the `against()` function?

The argument needs to extract the user's input from the last page.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) you place the keywords in the against function.

```
$keywords = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name of the input box']);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('".$keywords."')");
```

Although i suggest using GET for search. No "Sure you want to post again" dialog on a page-refresh and you can modify the search criteria without the form.